# How to parse sql queries from log files and network protocols using ANTLRv4

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr4

I need to parse SQL queries that can be submitted using network protocol (e.g. MySQL protocol) or stored in log files.

I built a parser based on ANTLRv4  [Tsql grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tsql/tsql.g4).

The following texts are valid in this grammar:

```
select 1
select 2
select 3
```

`select 1 select 2 select 3`

At the same time, they should not be valid for the network protocol because xSQL-server will delete `\n` and the final queries will be equal to `select 1 select 2 select 3`.

Is it possible to create a grammar that will handle both cases? Or I should create and support two grammars: First grammar to parse logs and second to parse network queries?
Can I use semantic predicates to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two approaches:

- Use code fragments in grammar:

  1. Delcare `textMode` flag at `@lexer::members` section.
  2. Replace `SPACE` token with the following ones:
     `ANTLR
     Whitespace: [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN);
     Linebreak: '\r'? '\n'
     { if (textMode)
         channel(HIDDEN);
      else
         AddParseError();
     }`
- Check tokens without grammar modification:

  1. Tokenize import. After this step we have the following tokens:
     `SELECT WS( ) NUMBER(1) WS(\n) SELECT WS( ) NUMBER(2) WS(\n) SELECT WS( ) NUMBER(2) WS(\n)`
  2. Loop over the tokens and do for every token:

     - If the "text mode" activated just ignore HIDDEN TOKENS (whitespaces and line breaks)
       After this step, we have the following tokens: `SELECT NUMBER(1) SELECT NUMBER(2) SELECT NUMBER(2)` which passed to parser.
     - If the "network protocol mode" activated add a custom error on `WS` token with line break value (`\r` or `\n`).

Comment: The both approaches do not solve the main problem: `select 1 select 2 select 3` will be parsed as valid query,  but it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You pose three questions at the end of your post, but I'll just provide one answer that has worked for me:  Simply create two grammars.  It's not as bad as it sounds and can clarify things.

You can make everything in the two grammars the same, and then include only the different sections with the `import <mysegment>` construct.  I've used this approach for medical HL7 files, which use and reuse many common segments.